# What does $c mean in a Windows Directory?

Tags: windows, server, directory

My boss gave me access to the company's private network via SonicFireWall. I can not access their files using my File Explorer. However, there is something that I don't understand.

There is a file/folder named c$ that seems to not exist only if your type it. 
[image]

You can access things in 'c$', like for example folder1/folder2/c$/file.txt. But when I back out c$, I cannot find c$.

meaning, When I am in folder1/folder2/, I cannot find c$. What is this? Is there a name for this type of file/folder?

Comment: I believe C$ is an [administrative share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share) that is enabled by default.  As per wikipedia, administrative shares are hidden, which would explain why you can't see them when you back out.  But I'm not sure how you can access something like `folder1/folder2/c$/file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

It means it is an "admin" share or "hidden" share. Therefore its not visible when a share list of the device is requested

Comment: Although the limitations on commenting while not having enough reputation are understandable, please refrain from posting comments as answers. If you know you have an answer to this question, please, edit it, elaborate it respecting the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing good answers.

Comment: @user3078414: looks like a perfectly good answer to me - except that the question was off-topic to begin with.  Some questions do have short, simple answers, and in those cases there's no good reason to pad them out just so they aren't "too short".  (A reference would have been nice, but they're not actually mandatory.)